# user.dir is incorrect while using tomcat web app in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, path, relative-path

I have a configuration project that few projects are using it.
All of my project under the same workingspace.

workingspace/configuration

workingspace/webapp1

workingspace/mongoDB

workingspace/model

mongoDB and the model project are using the configuration jar project and able to read the xml files using relative path ../configuration/conf/....xml

when using the

```
 System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                          System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

inside both of them, I'm getting the correct path (workspace)

while trying to do it from the web app servlet i'm getting the folder of eclipse.exe that causing some problems.

How can i fix the user.dir defalte path for the web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, e.g. when you're not running from inside eclipse, you probably want to work in a defined directory as well - I'd suggest to explicitly configure a specific directory. When you're running within an appserver, you might run as an unpriviledged user that doesn't have a home directory writeable at all (when the account is properly administered with minimal permissions). This differs from applications that are launched ad hoc. In fact, you probably can't assume that your application server runs as the same user as your standalone apps do.

Another alternative is to utilize the system's temp directory - if these are truly temporary files. This could be assumed writeable, or complaints if it isn't do make sense.